# Vim: use tab key for autocompletion with Autocomplpop plugin

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm using basic autocompletion in Vim along with the [Autocomplpop](https://github.com/othree/vim-autocomplpop) plugin, which automatically shows available completions when I start typing. Once I've typed enough to narrow down the list to the word I want, I'd like to be able to hit tab to choose that completion. With the script below, two tab presses are required instead of one, and I'm not sure why.

```
" Tab completion
" will insert tab at beginning of line,
" will use completion if not at beginning
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full
function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <Tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
inoremap <S-Tab> <c-n>
```

Comment: I forked Autocomplpop a while ago and wanted to use `<Tab>` too. [Here is my solution](https://github.com/romainl/acp-forked/blob/master/autoload/acp.vim#L211-L212).

Comment: You might also want to browse http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use `return "\<c-y>"` instead of `return "\<c-p>"`.

Comment: Can you explain how and why this might work? … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

the below function did the job

```
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full

function! InsertTabWrapper()
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    else
        return "\<c-p>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <tab> InsertTabWrapper()
inoremap <s-tab> <c-n>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `return "\<c-n>"` instead of `return "\<c-p>"`.